# How to access List's properties in Spring EL?

Tags: java, spring, properties, javabeans, el

EL tries to interpret property name as List index and fails. How to access List's normal bean properties if they are exist?

**UPDATE**

I had my own class

```
public class Directory extends AbstractList<File> {

    ...

    public Date getInternetLastModified() {
       return internetLastModified;
    }
```

As you see this class is both list and has individual properties.

When I wrote in XML:

```
${directory.internetLastModified}
```

I was getting `NumberFormatException`. I interpreted this, that since an object is a List, EL was trying to do something like

```
out.print(directory.get( String.valueOf("internetLastModified" ) )
```

So this leads me to ask this question.

Comment: i don't get you. are you trying to print a list entry from your model?

Comment: How are you accessing it?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're trying to get from the List?

Comment: I just want to confirm that you intend getInternetLastModified is an instance method. Is that so?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the internetLastModified is an instance method, created a simple Directory class, and tried the SpelExpressionParser to see what happened.

```
public class DirectoryExamplesMain {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        org.springframework.expression.Expression exp = null;

        Directory dir = new Directory();

        // Literal
        exp = parser.parseExpression("internetLastModified");
        Date d = exp.getValue(dir, Date.class);
        System.out.format("internetLastModified", d);


    }
}
```

And the result I got was `internetLastModified [Fri May 03 15:40:44 CDT 2013]`

If directory is a bean  think what you need to use `"@directory.internetLastModified"` as the expression. You can find examples like this in section 7.5 of the reference manual.

Here's an easy way to test that.

```
import java.util.Date;

import org.springframework.expression.AccessException;
import org.springframework.expression.BeanResolver;
import org.springframework.expression.EvaluationContext;
import org.springframework.expression.ExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser;
import org.springframework.expression.spel.support.StandardEvaluationContext;

public class DirectoryExamplesMain {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        final ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

    // Bean references
    final StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    context.setBeanResolver(
        new BeanResolver() {
        @Override
        public Object resolve(EvaluationContext arg0, String arg1)
            throws AccessException {
             return new Directory();
    }});

    System.out.format("%s [%s]%n","@directory.internetLastModified",  parser.parseExpression("@directory.internetLastModified").getValue(context));
}
```